# Element wise subtraction inside a matrix and record results in table format using R

Tags: r, matrix

Example I have a matrix data

```
     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
[1,] 1     2     3     4     5     6
[2,] 7     8     9    10     11    12
[3,] 13   14    15    16     17    18
[4,] 19   20    21    22     23    24   
[5,] 25   26    27    28     29    30
```

Now I wanted to do column-wise subtraction
like

```
   var1  var2  var3   var4   var5    var6
[1,] 1     1-2    2-3    3-4    4-5    5-6
[2,] 7     7-8    8-9    9-10   10-11  11-12
[3,] 13   13-14   14-15  15-16  16-17  17-18
[4,] 19   19-20   20-21  21-22  22-23  23-24   
[5,] 25   25-26   26-27  27-28  28-29  29-30
```

And store the results in table format
like

```
|  A        |   B       |  difference |
| --------- | --------- | ----------- |
| var1[1,]  |  var2[1,] |  1          |
| var2[1,]  |  var3[1,] |  1          |
| var3[1,]  |  var4[1,] |  1          |
| var4[1,]  |  var5[1,] |  1          |
| var5[1,]  |  var6[1,] |  1          |
| var1[2,]  |  var2[2,] |  1          |
| var2[2,]  |  var3[2,] |  1          |
| var3[2,]  |  var4[2,] |  1          |
| var4[2,]  |  var5[2,] |  1          |
| var5[2,]  |  var6[2,] |  1          |
```

I need an R code to achieve it.

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code like below

```
out1 <- `colnames<-`(cbind(mat[, 1], mat[, -ncol(mat)] - mat[, -1]), colnames(mat))

out2 <- transform(data.frame(A = c(t(mat[, -ncol(mat)])), B = c(t(mat[, -1]))), difference = A - B)

cn <- colnames(mat)
inds <- rep(seq(nrow(mat)), each = ncol(mat) - 1)
out3 <- data.frame(
  A = paste0(rep(cn[-length(cn)], each = nrow(mat)), "_", inds),
  B = paste0(rep(cn[-1], each = nrow(mat)), "_", inds),
  difference = c(t(out1[, -1]))
)
```

such that

```
> out1
     var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
[1,]    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[2,]    7   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[3,]   13   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[4,]   19   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[5,]   25   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1

> out2
    A  B difference
1   1  2         -1
2   2  3         -1
3   3  4         -1
4   4  5         -1
5   5  6         -1
6   7  8         -1
7   8  9         -1
8   9 10         -1
9  10 11         -1
10 11 12         -1
11 13 14         -1
12 14 15         -1
13 15 16         -1
14 16 17         -1
15 17 18         -1
16 19 20         -1
17 20 21         -1
18 21 22         -1
19 22 23         -1
20 23 24         -1
21 25 26         -1
22 26 27         -1
23 27 28         -1
24 28 29         -1
25 29 30         -1

> out3
        A      B difference
1  var1_1 var2_1         -1
2  var1_1 var2_1         -1
3  var1_1 var2_1         -1
4  var1_1 var2_1         -1
5  var1_1 var2_1         -1
6  var2_2 var3_2         -1
7  var2_2 var3_2         -1
8  var2_2 var3_2         -1
9  var2_2 var3_2         -1
10 var2_2 var3_2         -1
11 var3_3 var4_3         -1
12 var3_3 var4_3         -1
13 var3_3 var4_3         -1
14 var3_3 var4_3         -1
15 var3_3 var4_3         -1
16 var4_4 var5_4         -1
17 var4_4 var5_4         -1
18 var4_4 var5_4         -1
19 var4_4 var5_4         -1
20 var4_4 var5_4         -1
21 var5_5 var6_5         -1
22 var5_5 var6_5         -1
23 var5_5 var6_5         -1
24 var5_5 var6_5         -1
25 var5_5 var6_5         -1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(mat)
structure(c(1L, 7L, 13L, 19L, 25L, 2L, 8L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 3L, 
9L, 15L, 21L, 27L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 5L, 11L, 17L, 23L,
29L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 30L), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(NULL,
    c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6")))
```

Comment: I need column names to be present in A & B, not the values

Comment: @ARUNAAS See `out3` in my update (not sure if that is what you are after)

Comment: similar to it, I need the matrix position of the variable like "var1(ij)" to make it unique.

Comment: @ARUNAAS See the upddate

Answer (score 1):

You can get the matrix with `diff` and `cbind`:

```
cbind(x[,1], t(-diff(t(x))[-1,]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[2,]    7   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[3,]   13   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[4,]   19   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[5,]   25   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

And the `data.frame` by using `t` and subseting with `y[-nrow(y),]` and `y[-1,]`

```
y <- t(x)
transform(data.frame(A=c(y[-nrow(y),]), B=c(y[-1,])), difference = A - B)
#    A  B difference
#1   1  2         -1
#2   2  3         -1
#3   3  4         -1
#4   4  5         -1
#5   5  6         -1
#6   7  8         -1
#7   8  9         -1
#8   9 10         -1
#9  10 11         -1
#...
```

Data:

```
x <- matrix(1:30, 5, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: I need column names to be present in A & B, not the values

Comment: You want something like `t(sapply(2:6, function(i) c(colnames(x)[i-1], colnames(x)[i])))` ?

Comment: similar to it, I need the matrix position of the variable like "var1(ij)" to make it unique.